# Splitting by html elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of strings that typically looks something like this:

```html
string 1<div>string 2<br></div>string 3
```

```html
string 1<div>string 2<br></div><div>string 3<br></div>
```

```html
<div>string 1<br></div><div>string 2<br></div><div>string 3<br></div>
```

And I need to extract the text (both inside and outside/between elements, as seen above) into an array like this:

```
['string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3']
```

Is there a way to do this in pure Javascript?

I tried something like this:

```js
console.log(text.split(/<div>(.*)<br><\/div>/g))
```

But it only works for the first one:

```js
[ 'string 1', 'string 2', 'string 3' ]
```

While it fails on the two last variations:

```js
[ 'string 1', 'string 2<br></div><div>string 3', '' ]
```

```js
[ '', 'string 1<br></div><div>string 2<br></div><div>string 3', '' ]
```

Comment: I'll try be sneaky with `.match(/(?<=>|^)[^<]+/g)`, but if the inputs can vary in some other way, this fails catastrophically.

Comment: There are lots of good approaches, including regex.  But I'd STRONGLY encourage you to consider jQuery.  "Pure Javascript" is NOT necessarily the best approach all time.  IMHO...

Comment: @ASDFGerte Thanks, I'll use this approach. It seems to work well for my case, for now. If you'd like, it'd be nice if you make a full answer elaborating how it works.

Comment: @paulsm4 I need to use this in Anki, which doesn't have great support for Javascript in the first place, so I want to keep it minimal. Plus I don't want my cards getting too heavy.

Comment: It's abusing the fact, that the text is always between `>` (or string start) and `<` (or string end), and nothing else is (at least no non-empty strings). It ignores everything else. Note, that look-behind isn't yet available everywhere, but if that is a problem, you can do something like match the `>` as well, and remove it afterwards.

Comment: It will also fail if the text contains a `<`...

Comment: Yeah, it is very unstable when it comes to "input doesn't conform to very strict rules". This is however often the case, and it's also unlikely to find rogue `<` in html-like text. It is however, why i am a bit reluctant to turn it into a full answer, because while it should work in the given case, it's not really robust, when anything changes even slightly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure JavaScript approach is generally better than regex for parsing HTML. You can create a `template` element, load the HTML into it and then use `Array.filter` to get all the child nodes which are text nodes, finally returning their `textContent`:

```js
const html = [
  'string 1<div>string 2<br></div>string 3',
  'string 1<div>string 2<br></div><div>string 3<br></div>',
  '<div>string 1<br></div><div>string 2<br></div><div>string 3<br></div>'
]

const getTextContent = (html) => {
  let tmp = document.createElement('template');
  tmp.innerHTML = html;
  const textNodes = [].filter.call(tmp.content.childNodes, n => n.nodeType = Node.TEXT_NODE);
  return textNodes.map(o => o.textContent);
}

html.forEach(h => console.log(getTextContent(h)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution but I tried your tree examples with this code :

```
let regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
let myArray = myString.replace(regex, "-").split("-");
```

You might want to change the - character by something else to be sure and you also need to filter your array to remove empty elements but it works